# Brute Force Caeser Cipher Python

Tags: python

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher

Hey all, I'm doing this as an assignment for Uni. I'm so close to finishing, yet I'm stuck on the last section. I'm sure it's something basic, but I've spent close to four hours trying to find my errors using print statements and all.

Basically the idea is that it will just brute force decrypt the user's encrypted message by cycling through all -26 offsets. My problem is that I can get the code to cycle through 26 times, but it simply will not decrypt the message for each offset.. if that makes sense.

Correct Sample Output:

```
Please enter string to decrypt: ykixkz&yw{oxxkr

Offset: -1 = Decrypted string: xjhwjy%xvznwwjq
Offset: -2 = Decrypted string: wigvix$wuymvvip
Offset: -3 = Decrypted string: vhfuhw#vtxluuho
Offset: -4 = Decrypted string: ugetgv"uswkttgn
Offset: -5 = Decrypted string: tfdsfu!trvjssfm
Offset: -6 = Decrypted string: secret squirrel
Offset: -7 = Decrypted string: rdbqds}rpthqqdk
Offset: -8 = Decrypted string: qcapcr|qosgppcj
Offset: -9 = Decrypted string: pb`obq{pnrfoobi
Offset: -10 = Decrypted string: oa_napzomqennah
Offset: -11 = Decrypted string: n`^m`oynlpdmm`g
Offset: -12 = Decrypted string: m_]l_nxmkocll_f
Offset: -13 = Decrypted string: l^\k^mwljnbkk^e
Offset: -14 = Decrypted string: k][j]lvkimajj]d
Offset: -15 = Decrypted string: j\Zi\kujhl`ii\c
Offset: -16 = Decrypted string: i[Yh[jtigk_hh[b
Offset: -17 = Decrypted string: hZXgZishfj^ggZa
Offset: -18 = Decrypted string: gYWfYhrgei]ffY`
Offset: -19 = Decrypted string: fXVeXgqfdh\eeX_
Offset: -20 = Decrypted string: eWUdWfpecg[ddW^
Offset: -21 = Decrypted string: dVTcVeodbfZccV]
Offset: -22 = Decrypted string: cUSbUdncaeYbbU\
Offset: -23 = Decrypted string: bTRaTcmb`dXaaT[
Offset: -24 = Decrypted string: aSQ`Sbla_cW``SZ
Offset: -25 = Decrypted string: `RP_Rak`^bV__RY
Offset: -26 = Decrypted string: _QO^Q`j_]aU^^QX
```

My output:

```
Please enter string to decrypt: ff

Offset: -1 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -2 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -3 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -4 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -5 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -6 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -7 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -8 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -9 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -10 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -11 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -12 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -13 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -14 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -15 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -16 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -17 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -18 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -19 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -20 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -21 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -22 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -23 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -24 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -25 = Decrypted string: ff
Offset: -26 = Decrypted string: ff
```

My code (I've cut most the program out)

```
choice = 0

print ('*** Menu ***\n')

print ('1. Encrypt string')
print ('2. Decrypt string')
print ('3. Brute force decryption')
print ('4. Quit\n')

    elif choice == 3:
        print ('In command 3 - Brute force')
        userString = input('\nPlease enter string to decrypt: ')
        userList = list(userString)
        offsetValue = 0
        decryptIndex = 0
        while offsetValue != -26 : # Once the count reaches -26 stop, hammer time
            while decryptIndex < len(userList):
                decryptChr = chr(ord(userList[decryptIndex]) + offsetValue)
                userList[decryptIndex] = decryptChr
                decryptIndex += 1
                offsetValue -= 1
            userString = ''.join(userList)
            print ('Offset',offsetValue,' = Decrypted string:' ,userString)
        print ('\n*** Menu ***\n')
        print ('1. Encrypt string')
        print ('2. Decrypt string')
        print ('3. Brute force decryption')
        print ('4. Quit\n')
        choice = int(input('What would you like to do? [1,2,3,4]? '))
        while choice != 1 and choice != 2 and choice != 3 and choice != 4:
            choice = int(input('\nPlease re-enter either [1,2,3,4] '))

print ('\nGoodbye.')
```

Any ideas?!

Comment: I notice that `offsetValue` isn't being reassigned...also, you should move that entire block of logic off to its own method and just call that, instead - makes testing and coding it that much easier.

Comment: The inner loops seem wrong. You should step through it (with debugger, or just in your head, keeping and updating variable values on paper). Someone might soon just give you a working loop, but if you're learning programming, it's important to understand what your posted code does and how it is wrong, so fix it yourself if you want to actually learn.

Comment: remove one indent off `offsetCount -= 1` and initialize `decryptIndex` to 0 just before the inner while loop.

Comment: Okay, this is exactly the feedback I'm looking for. I would rather not get the exact answer, but rather find where I've gone wrong.

Comment: A style comment: In Python, it's far more natural to use `for` loops over a sequence or range rather than `while` loops with increment statements. Your first loop on `offsetValue` could be directly translated `for offsetValue in range(-1, -27, -1)` (this would fix one of your errors, since the value is getting permanently mutated in the inner loop).  The inner loop could be minimally changed to `for decryptIndex in range(len(userList))` or you could make a somewhat larger change and iterate over the string directly with `for userChar in userString` (and use `append` to build the `userList`).

Answer (score 2):

Much easier to use `str.translate`

```
chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
rot1 = str.maketrans(chars, chars[1:]+chars[0])

message = input()

for i in chars:
    print(message)
    message = message.translate(rot1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A much neater way to decode Caesar cyphers in Python is to make use of string slicing.

Take the alphabet, ie:

```
src = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Now for each possibility, with shift `n = 0, ..., 25`, we can build a new character set for the cypher:

```
for n in range(26):
    dest = src[n:] + src[:n]
```

You can then decode a string `s` by looking up the position of each character in the source and destination sets:

```
    decoded = ''.join(dest[src.index(c)] for c in s)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your original program is that the line

`offsetValue -= 1`

is improperly indented.

You don't reinitialise the loop counter, plus you can possibly cause chr to throw an error due to `ord(userList[decryptIndex]) + offsetValue` being an invalid character.

Converting to a list and back is unwieldly and unnecessary. It is much cleaner to use string concatenation. Though for a really clean solution, the other solutions show the pythonic way to solve this problem.

So your program should be:

```
choice = 0

print ('*** Menu ***\n')

print ('1. Encrypt string')
print ('2. Decrypt string')
print ('3. Brute force decryption')
print ('4. Quit\n')

    elif choice == 3:
        print ('In command 3 - Brute force')
        userString = input('\nPlease enter string to decrypt: ')
        offsetValue = 0

        while offsetValue != -26 : # Once the count reaches -26 stop, hammer time
            decryptIndex = 0
            decryptedString = ""
            while decryptIndex < len(userString):
                c = ord(userString[decryptIndex]) + offsetValue 
                if c < 0: c += 128
                decryptChr = chr(c)
                decryptedString += decryptChr
                decryptIndex += 1
            offsetValue -= 1
            print ('Offset',offsetValue,' = Decrypted string:' ,decryptedString)
        print ('\n*** Menu ***\n')
        print ('1. Encrypt string')
        print ('2. Decrypt string')
        print ('3. Brute force decryption')
        print ('4. Quit\n')
        choice = int(input('What would you like to do? [1,2,3,4]? '))
        while choice != 1 and choice != 2 and choice != 3 and choice != 4:
            choice = int(input('\nPlease re-enter either [1,2,3,4] '))

print ('\nGoodbye.')
```

Comment: Answer incomplete, there are more problems in the program. Complete it and I will surely undo it :)

Comment: There is something wrong with `decryptChr = chr(ord(userList[decryptIndex]) + offsetValue)` as well.

Comment: Good spotting @nims. I'm not sure if my explanation is correct.

Comment: raw_input has been removed in python 3, so I'm not going to make that change.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29154/discussion-between-dominicmcdonnell-and-nims)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something along these lines:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet 
import string

def caesar(plaintext, shift):
    shifted_alphabet = alphabet[shift:] + alphabet[:shift]
    table = string.maketrans(alphabet, shifted_alphabet)
    return plaintext.translate(table)

plain='hello there'  
shift=3
coded=caesar(plain,shift)  
decoded=caesar(coded,-shift)    
print plain
print coded
print decoded
```

Prints:

```
hello there
khoor wkhuh
hello there
```

Answer (score 0):

I will steal shamelessly from gnibbler as his is the best answer so far.

I am a bit worried about your menu handling though. You print out your menu and then inside the choice you print it again. Maybe such an "old-school" CLI-menu can be handled a bit more elegantly.

I am not contributing to the actual answer of gnibbler (who for sure got my upvote), but I try to address another issue, which maybe and hopefully might help you to get "nicer" code.

This is my idea:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

import sys
from collections import defaultdict

menu = '''
*** Menu ***
[1] Encrypt
[2] Decrypt
[3] Brute force
[4] Quit
'''

def caesar (s, offset):
    chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    return s.translate (str.maketrans (chars, chars [offset:] + chars [:offset] ) )

def decrypt ():
    s = input ('Enter string to decrypt: ')
    offset = int (input ('Enter offset: ') )
    print (caesar (s, (-offset) % 26) )

def encrypt ():
    s = input ('Enter string to encrypt: ')
    offset = int (input ('Enter offset: ') )
    print (caesar (s, offset) )

def bruteForce ():
    s = input ('Enter string to brute force: ')
    for offset in range (26):
        print ('Offset {}:\t{}'.format (offset, caesar (s, (-offset) % 26) ) )

def unrecognized ():
    print ('unrecognized command')

options = {'1': encrypt,
           '2': decrypt,
           '3': bruteForce,
           '4': sys.exit}

options = defaultdict (lambda: unrecognized, options)

while ...: options [input (menu) ] ()
```

(inb4 "weird whitespacing")